Retrieve historical candle data by dayofweek and specific time
I try to build an indicator to get the ranges of candles by the same day of week, hour and minute, then to compare the current candle range with the average.
I use last_bar_time to get the bar time of last candle displayed by the chart.
When the engine loops through bar_indexes from 0 till the end, if the dayofweek, hour and time are matched with last_bar_time details, store the values in an array.
At first iteration of script it works ok, but when i play Next candle in replay or is a new candle in realtime, data is not updated in array.
I attached code where i store candle details (day hour min) and is not working ok. Thank you.
//@version=5
indicator('Ca Range', "Ca Range", overlay=true, max_lines_count=500, max_boxes_count=500, max_labels_count=500 ,  max_bars_back = 4999 )


TIMEZONE = 'America/New_York'

int timenow_year            = year( timenow, TIMEZONE )
int timenow_month           = month( timenow, TIMEZONE )
int timenow_dayofmonth      = dayofmonth( timenow, TIMEZONE ) // 1...31
int timenow_dayofweek       = dayofweek( timenow, TIMEZONE )
int timenow_hour            = hour( timenow, TIMEZONE )
int timenow_minute          = minute( timenow, TIMEZONE )
int timenow_seconds         = second( timenow, TIMEZONE )


int time_year               = year( time, TIMEZONE )
int time_month              = month( time, TIMEZONE )
int time_dayofmonth         = dayofmonth( time, TIMEZONE ) // 1...31
int time_dayofweek          = dayofweek( time, TIMEZONE )
int time_hour               = hour( time, TIMEZONE )
int time_minute             = minute( time, TIMEZONE )
int time_seconds            = second( time, TIMEZONE )

string time_ymd             = str.format_time(time, "yyy-M-d", TIMEZONE )
string time_day_name_long   = str.format_time(time, "EEEE", TIMEZONE )


int last_bar_time_year            = year( last_bar_time, TIMEZONE )
int last_bar_time_month           = month( last_bar_time, TIMEZONE )
int last_bar_time_dayofmonth      = dayofmonth( last_bar_time, TIMEZONE ) // 1...31
int last_bar_time_dayofweek       = dayofweek( last_bar_time, TIMEZONE )
int last_bar_time_hour            = hour( last_bar_time, TIMEZONE )
int last_bar_time_minute          = minute( last_bar_time, TIMEZONE )
int last_bar_time_seconds         = second( last_bar_time, TIMEZONE )


 

var arr_candles_by_dayofweek_hour_min = array.new_string() 
 

if array.size(arr_candles_by_dayofweek_hour_min) > 2 
    array.shift(arr_candles_by_dayofweek_hour_min)




ca_0_range_id_day_name_cond = 
     time_hour == last_bar_time_hour 
     and time_minute == last_bar_time_minute  
     and time_dayofweek == last_bar_time_dayofweek


if ca_0_range_id_day_name_cond

    array.push(arr_candles_by_dayofweek_hour_min, 
         ""
         + str.tostring(time_ymd) 
         + " "
         + str.tostring(time_day_name_long) 
         + " "
         + str.tostring(time_hour) 
         + ":" 
         + str.tostring(time_minute)  
         )



var label lbl_3 = na
label.delete(lbl_3)
lbl_3 := label.new (barstate.islast ? bar_index  : na, 
     y=close, 
     xloc=xloc.bar_index, 
     yloc=yloc.abovebar, 
     style = label.style_label_down,
     size = size.large,
     color = color.new(color.aqua, 60),
     textcolor = color.new(color.black, 0),
     textalign = text.align_left,
     text = "" 
          + str.tostring(  arr_candles_by_dayofweek_hour_min   )
        //   + "\n" +  str.tostring(  timenow_hour   ) 
         , 
     tooltip = "" + str.tostring( bar_index )
     )  







